# Easiest way to have Python 2 and 3 coexist on Mac OSX 10.8 with Anaconda installed

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, anaconda

I am using python 2.7.10 with Anaconda 2.3.0, and I use the Anaconda IDE with sublime text 3 (is it a different Anaconda??).
However, for a course I'm taking we're required to use python 3.5.

I would like to keep python 2.7 on my computer, though. What would be the easiest way to have both versions coexist and be easily accessible through the terminal (through sublime would be great, but I'd be happy with managing it on the terminal for now)?

Also, I typically run `conda update conda`, and `conda update anaconda` on a regular basis to keep everything up to date. How would that work with different versions of python installed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sort of thing is actually what Anaconda is built for. Although the default Python version depends on the installer you used, Anaconda supports both versions. The easiest way is to create a new virtual environment. From the following [link](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/py2or3.html#create-python-2-or-3-environments), use this `conda` command to build a Python 3 environment:

```
conda create -n py35 python=3.5 anaconda
```

That is if you need Python 3.5 with all the `anaconda` packages. You can either leave that blank if you just want a vanilla version of Python 3.5, or specify individual packages.

Once you do this, Python 3.5 will be available with the console command `py35`. You should definitely read the following link about how to [manage environments](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/envs.html). Really, you should read that whole tutorial.

Comment: Thank you for all the details and links, this is very helpful.