# pandas working in ipython notebook with python 2.7 but NOT with python 3.5

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas, anaconda

After asking this question, I installed environments for both python 2.7 and python 3.5: [Easiest way to have Python 2 and 3 coexist on Mac OSX 10.8 with Anaconda installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39259833/easiest-way-to-have-python-2-and-3-coexist-on-mac-osx-10-8-with-anaconda-install/39260397#39260397)

i also manually installed kernels for both python versions. If I start in my terminal the py35 environment (`source activate py35`) and then `ipython notebook`, i can choose a kernel that lets me use either python 2.7 or python 3.5.

Up to this point, everything is good.

However, when I run a check of all the modules I'm going to need, including ipython, numpy, scipy, pandas, scikitlearn, etc...using commands such as: 
`import pandas`
`print("Pandas version:       %6.6s " % pandas.__version__)`

the notebook crashes when it gets to **pandas**, even though I checked manually with `conda list` and pandas is indeed installed and updated to the last version.

What's interesting is that if i run the same checks using the python 2.7 kernel, everything runs smoothly, **including the pandas command**.

What's going on?

EDIT: Here's the kind of feedback I get upon crashing:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-3b71b0be8baa> in <module>()
     12 
     13 # Pandas makes working with data tables easier
---> 14 import pandas
     15 print("Pandas version:       %6.6s (need at least 0.16.2)" % pandas.__version__)
     16
```

then more of that...and at the very end:

**`ValueError: unknown locale: UTF-8`**

Comment: Try this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15526996/ipython-notebook-locale-error

Comment: Or this: http://conda.pydata.org/docs/troubleshooting.html#unknown-locale

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, it worked! I would've never found that out by myself or it would've taken me forever, thank you so much.